# Why is Python showing error : can't assign to operator?

Tags: python

```py
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
q = int(now.strftime('%I'))
w = int(now.strftime('%M'))

def correct_time(delta):
    if w < (120 - delta):
        Q = q + 1 and W = w + (delta - 60)
    else:
        Q = q + 2 and W = w + (delta - 120)
    return Q, W

correct_time(45)

#gives error - SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

In the above code I was trying to assign new values of q and w to Q and W respectively. I get no error when I only try to assign new value to either Q or W (not to both in the same line) but when I use 'and'(as in the above case) or ',' I get such an error.

I searched the internet for 'can't assign to operator' error but found that they were not relevant to my case. I would like to know why the above code shows error when it follows the rules of assignment.

Comment: Your use of `and` doesn't make sense. You are trying to use it to sequence actions rather than combine truth values.

Comment: `foo = bar and baz = qux` means `foo = (bar and baz) = qux`, not `(foo = bar)` and `(baz = qux)`. You get the error because you can't assign to an expression (`bar and baz`)

Comment: Wouldn't even a ',' (comma) be acceptable to separate the expression (as desired here) ?

Comment: Simply put, you are trying to use logical operators where you shouldn't. Logical operators perform Logical `AND`, `OR` and `NOT` operations. (eg. if `a` and `b``:`...)

Comment: maybe a `;` but why do that? Just separate each statement in its own line. Much more readable

Comment: You could use a comma like this: `Q, W = q+1, w + (delta - 60)`, but that use of the comma is an example of tuple unpacking rather than a statement delimiter. This particular example of tuple unpacking wouldn't be as readable as just using two lines, and in Python [readability counts](https://zen-of-python.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We all know that only `expression and expression` is valid. So the point here is that in Python, `assignment` is just a `statement`, not `expression`. In `C`, `a = 3` is `assignment expression` and `a = 3 && b = 4` is valid. But, this is not valid in Python.

And Python will have its own `assignment expression` in 3.8: [PEP 572 -- Assignment Expressions | Python.org](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

In  Python3.8, you will be able to do such thing:

```
# This block code only works with Python3.8+
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
q = int(now.strftime('%I'))
w = int(now.strftime('%M'))

def correct_time(delta):
    if w < (120 - delta):
        (Q := q + 1) and (W := w + (delta - 60))
    else:
        (Q := q + 2) and (W := w + (delta - 120))
    return Q, W

correct_time(45)
```

But, it is not necessary, since you can just do such thing in Python:

```
a, b = 1, 2
```

which equals to

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be:

```
def correct_time(delta):
    if w < (120 - delta):
        Q = q + 1
        W = w + (delta - 60)
    else:
        Q = q + 2
        W = w + (delta - 120)
    return Q, W
```

In an expression like `a = 1 and b = 2`, Python would first try to assign the value `2` to `a and b`, which is impossible and produces the error `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`. You would get something similar with `a = 1 = 2`: here, trying to assign `2` to `1` would produce `SyntaxError: can't assign to literal`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the following syntax:

```
def correct_time(delta):
    if w < (120 - delta):
        Q, W = q + 1, w + (delta - 60)
    else:
        Q, W = q + 2, w + (delta - 120)
    return Q, W
```

In your case it doesn't work because right hand should be expression but it's 
`expression` and `statement` (due to assignment).